# Is finding the closure of a space a method of the completion of a metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose we have a metric space $(X,d)$. I wonder whether finding the closure of it is the completion of the metric space?

### My thinking

I do know the defination of the completion of a metric space. It seems it's more general and complex than just find the closure. But why we need such a complex defination if clusure can make the space complete?

Comment: By axiom, a topological space is itself always closed (and also open). So the closure of $X$ is $X$, unless I am misunderstanding something...

Comment: For example, a open ball is not closed. Is there anything misleading in my stating of the problem?

Comment: The open ball is not closed when you look at it inside an ambient space, say $\mathbb{R}^n$ for instance. This is what is usually meant. However, the open ball surely is closed for the induced topology on it. In your statement, I think you need to mention that $(X,d)$ embeds inside an ambient (metric) space. Then however, I am no expert to answer your question.

Comment: Just a little bit confuse. For example, what if we don't mention the ambient space of  $\mathbb{Q}$? Some sequence still converge out of the set, how to describe this situation?

Comment: @maple If a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ to a value in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, then we say that the sequence *doesn't converge in* $\mathbb{Q}$. A priori, there is no "ambient space", so the sequence doesn't converge.

Comment: That's the point of considering the completion: intuitively, Cauchy sequences "should" converge, so we create a space in which all of the "gaps" are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Its closure in $\mathbb{Q}$ is $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, but this space is not complete. Its completion would be $[0,1]$, as a subset of real numbers.

Similarly, $\mathbb{Q}$, $(0,1)$, an open ball in any metric space, etc. are closed *in themselves*, but are not equal to their completion. Recall that a space $Y \subset X$ is closed *in $X$* if the complement $X \backslash Y$ is open. If $Y=X$, then this complement is the empty set, and the empty set is certainly open.